# ble: send data in onConnection Callback function

Tags: c++, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to program a ble chip that sends data to a device, as soon as the two connect. I´m programming the ble chip in C++.

My plan was to use updateCharacteristicValue inside my connectionCallback function. However, the data does not get sent, although the function is called. My serial port prints "connected" and "data sent" but the data is not received by my phone.

My connectionCallback function looks like this:

```
void connectionCallback(const Gap::ConnectionCallbackParams_t *params) {
    pc.printf("connected \r\n");

    uint8_t rx_buf[7];
    rx_buf[0] = 'D';
    rx_buf[1] = 'a';
    rx_buf[2] = 't';
    rx_buf[3] = 'a';
    rx_buf[4] = ':';
    rx_buf[5] = ' ';
    rx_buf[6] = '6';

    ble.updateCharacteristicValue(rxCharacteristic.getValueAttribute().getHandle(), rx_buf, 7, false);  
    pc.printf("data sent \r\n"); 

}
```

I call the function in main method, as usual:

```
ble.gap().onConnection(connectionCallback);
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: And what ble sdk/platform are you using?

Comment: I am using the BLE Nano from RedBear Lab. It has the nRF51822 on it. I am programming/compiling on mbed.org

Comment: Has anyone of you already done something like that? maybe the problem is with the ble or the receiving part?